CosmosDB - Can't use Dedicated Gateway with Virtual Network
I recently connected our CosmosDB to a virtual network, but after doing so I encountered an error when trying to execute an action that normally works:
Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.CosmosException : Response status code does not indicate success: Forbidden (403); Substatus: 0;
RequestUri: https://xxxxx.sqlx.cosmos.azure.com/

I changed the connection string to use documents.azure.com, and the forbidden error went away - at this point, CosmosDB is now working on the virtual network. However, by changing my connection string I have lost connection to the Dedicated Gateway. I would like to continue using Dedicated Gateway, but the 403 error is currently preventing that.
The only clue I've found is this outdated post (https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/83467) mentioning a limitation that Dedicated Gateway and a Virtual Network cannot be used together, however that limitation has since been removed from the official documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/dedicated-gateway#limitations). Is this limitation still in effect, and is this why I can't use the two together? Or could it be something else?

Dedicated gateway with vnet with limiting is prevented refer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/dedicated-gateway @kendo


CosmosDB - Can't use Dedicated Gateway with Virtual Network due to 403 error.

The point you mentioned is correct as per latest Microsoftdoc the limitation was lifted off on certain sets of Db's.
The blocker you mentioned Forbidden (403) occurs for the multiple cases like it depends on the Network Security Rules, Private Endpoint DNS Resolution (if in case you're using private endpoint), firewall rules etc.

You mentioned that you use documents.azure.com resolved the 403 error but by chaning the connection string you need to ensure the correct format of the new connection sting.
AccountEndpoint=https://<your-account-name>.sqlx.cosmos.azure.com:443/;AccountKey=<your-account-key>;

As the latest doc mentioned that the limitation was removed it ultimately the issue was seems to be with the connection string and verify Dedicated Gateway is enabled for your CosmosDB account.
Refer:
Troubleshoot forbidden exceptions - Azure Cosmos DB for NoSQL | Microsoft Learn
